# Make a block display in one page and not in other

Tags: blocks, theming, 7

I am using Drupal 7 with omega and adminimal theme. I use adminimal theme for my iframe in the site (using entity iframe module). I would like to display a block in the adminimal theme alone, but not in my omega theme.

I used the default block settings, "Only the listed pages", but this display the block in both the themes.

So is there a way to configure the display options per theme?

Any help would be widely appreciated.

Comment: In block's `Region settings` you can find the block visibility settings on the basis of theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the block's `Region settings` you can specify the block to be displayed in which region of respective themes(Admin and site theme) as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `admin/structure/block` and then select the **theme tab** that you want to disable the block and then select none for the block you don't want to appear. See the below screen shot for better understanding.

[image]